# Slick js carousel flickers on load

Tags: css, slick.js

So I am using this carousel on my project http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/
Whenever I press f5, I can see huge column or width bugged items for like a sec, then it goes to normal. Same thing is happening on their page if u press f5 couple of times. Is there way to get rid of it? It really ruins my entire project with this.

Comment: You mean that some content jumps position when content on top finished loading? One way to fix that is to make everything in the document hidden with CSS, and then make it visible after the DOMContentLoaded event has fired.

Comment: I tried this aswell, I added display none style to the slide container, then I did `$(".desk-slider").attr("style", "display: flex !important");` after slide initialization but it's still happening :/

Comment: Do not add `display:none` property instead use `visibility:hidden` to the parent element of the carousel and make sure that its loaded and has taken the offset height > 0 it will change to `visibility:visible;`

Comment: Also sometimes when I press f5, the page turns in size twice as big for a second because it's in column.. is there way to block this?

Comment: I tried adding max-height !important aswell overflow hidden, still doesn't work :/

Comment: Are you using lazy loading on the slick carousel?

Comment: @ale917k I am not using lazy loading. I use this carousel and display items in it from for loop.

Comment: Make sure you have these styles in your carousel - https://github.com/ivoilic/react-slick-styles/blob/master/slick/slick-theme.css and https://github.com/ivoilic/react-slick-styles/blob/master/slick/slick.css

Comment: How can I check if the DOMContentLoaded was fired?

Comment: I tried adding div visbility hidden, then after `$("divname").slick({})` `$(".divname").css('visibility', 'visible');` Im not sure if this is correct way

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that slick() inserts bunch of DIV's and styles after it is loaded, which causes all these annoying quirks.

The way it should've been done is that the DIV's would've had the exact classnames before the slick() is even loaded.

What you can do is deactivate the slick() and make it look as same as the website with activated slick().
You will notice that when it's NOT activated, the website is very long and not looking good.